# Association of jboss-maven-plugin with jboss as server version

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jboss, pom.xml

How can I associate jboss-maven-plugin version with undelying server version?

For example:

```
  <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.8.Final</version>
```

is associated with 6.3 JBoss server. But I can't find a reference for other versions. Some help?

Comment: What's the source for "version 7.8 is associated with JBoss 6.3"?  The pom of any 7.x version of the plugin says "JBoss AS7 Deployment Plugin".

Comment: my version deploys 6.3...

Comment: Do you need to associate the server version for some reason? What goals do you typlically run?

Comment: It's a request from the customer